# Why do we use DependecyInjection instead of OnConfiguring Method in the DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I have a class called StudentDbContext. I call theOnConfiguring method in it. I saw that dependency injection is used in some training videos. Here we already use context once. Why should I use dependency injection instead of OnConfiguring?

Option-1

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("...");
    }
```

Option-2

```
public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> context) : base(context)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Database interaction is the archetypal use of DI. You develop an application that interacts via an interface with any given RDBS. You then implement classes to implement the database interface for each supported RDBS. My main App supports SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySql and MS Access. If you let your clients decide, which RDBS they prefer, then your application will have a greater potential customer base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cs
> protected override void OnConfiguring(
>     DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
> {
>     optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("...");
> }
> ```

With this approach, you decide exactly which provider (MySQL) and which connection-string to use within `StudentDbContext` directly. If you want to change this to use a different provider or connection-string, you'll have to modify the `StudentDbContext` class directly. For example, consider a situation where you want to use a different provider for Development vs Production.

> ```cs
> public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> context)
>     : base(context) { }
> ```

This approach allows you to configure both the provider and the connection-string from outside of the `StudentDbContext`.

Using Dependency Injection, you'll see something like this in `Startup.ConfigureServices` (or *Program.cs* with ASP .NET Core 6):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySQL("...");
});
```

This second approach becomes more powerful when you want to use different providers/connection-strings (or even other settings) based on an environment, for example:

```cs
if (hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySQL("...");
    });
}
else
{
    services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("...");
    });
}
```

Comment: what about migrations? While running "dotnet ef database update"

Answer (score 0):

With dependency injection the DbContext doesn't need to know about the actual database in use. Furthermore, the DbContext doesn't even need to know which configuration settings should be used for establishing database connections.

This makes your code more independent. This e.g. makes your code more testable. There are other advantages, too.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can  also configure both approaches for use

db context

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(
    DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
 if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
  {
     optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("...");
  }
}
```

or startup configuration

```
  services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySQL("...");
    });
```

in this case if you don't configure the startup configuration or if you are using you db context in another project without dependency injection will be uses a local db contex configuration, otherwise global.